# Making a crawler with HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to make a webcrawler to gather links and information from a specific website. I also need to use Apache HTTP Client to do, and I've been glancing and looking over the tutorial on the website for a few days and I'm getting nowhere. Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to use apache HTTPClient to grab the HTML so I can parse through it. Frankly, it may be a case of misunderstanding what HTTPClient is supposed to be used for. Anything help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a kind of a college assignment or that kind of exercise? I'm asking because in modern web sites it is almost not possible to find straight actual HTML returned and captured by things like HTTPClient. In most cases you can get bunch of links to java script files...

Comment: Mmm, well, I need to navigate a website, and hyperlinks on the website to find get the titles, and authors of articles and the like.

Answer (score 0):

h-m-m... here it is, but... do not be surprised if you will see not what you see in the browser. As I said you will get what server actually returns by request:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       
    HostConfiguration hostConfig = new HostConfiguration();
    hostConfig.setHost("my.site.com", 80, Protocol.getProtocol("http"));
    client.setHostConfiguration(hostConfig);
    GetMethod getHtmlPageMethod = new GetMethod("/myPage.html");
    getHtmlPageMethod.setFollowRedirects(true);     
    try {
        int responseCode = client.executeMethod(getHtmlPageMethod);
        System.out.println("Got response code: " + responseCode);           
        if (200 == responseCode) {
            System.out.println("Response code 200 - SUCCESS ... go for response body... ");
            String responseBody = getHtmlPageMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
            if (null != responseBody) {
                System.out.println("Got body string:" + System.lineSeparator());
                System.out.println(responseBody);
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("No response body returned!");
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's Apache htmlclient 4.x? I'm fairly certain that GetMethod is in htmlclient 3.x, while in 4.x it's HttpGet. It seems like HostConfiguratioon and HttpClient are both different, as the former is no longer a library term, and HttpClient  is now abstract so it can't be instantiated like that.

Comment: Yes it is 3.x Does it matter? GetMethod or HttpGet...  I had no intention to write actual code for you. Sorry. It is an idea how to deal with http calls.

Comment: That's fair. It does give me more of an idea of what it should look like regardless, thanks~